# Android Studio: Google Maps Activity works on device from desktop but not from laptop

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have been working on a project with a Google Maps fragment on my desktop. When I run the app on my Google Pixel XL from my desktop, it works fine. However, I cloned the repository onto my laptop, and when I try to run the app on my phone from my laptop, the Google Maps fragment is just blank. I have downloaded the Google Play services SDK on both my desktop and laptop, and the API key is the same on both. Any suggestions?

Comment: add your laptop android studio SHA1 key to google developer account then download json file and put it inside app folder clean and run

Comment: Both provided solutions work! However, an alternative which I chose to do was to remove my desktop's SHA1 key from the credentials so that the access was unrestricted. For purposes of this project (small-scale uni assignment), I felt this was appropriate so my partners wouldn't have to add their SHA1 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your laptop SHA1 key to google developer account then download json file and put it inside app folder.

And if you change your device again you need to add another SHA1 of that device again. to google developer account.

Below is the link :-
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials